# Django Heroku Profile

Tags: python, django, heroku, procfile

I am having trouble running my django app on Heroku. Following is my file structures:

```
---django_blog
   ---media_cdn
   ---static_cdn
   ---Procfile
   ---requirements.txt
   ---runtime.txt
   ---src
      ---blog
         ---...
         ---settings.py
      ---manage.py
      ---...
```

So 'src' is actually is my project root, and 'blog' is my app. I tried made the procfile to be

```
web: blog.wsgi --log-file -
```

and

```
web: src.blog.wsgi --log-file -
```

But none of them works. When I checked the heroku logs file, I found this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'blog'
```

Comment: Read the https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#the-procfile, it will clear things out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Heroku` documentation:

> First, and most importantly, Heroku web applications require a
>   Procfile.
>
> This file (named Procfile) is used to explicitly declare your
>   application’s process types and entry points. It is located in the
>   root of your repository.

You need to be more specific about how you declare your process types, if you are using `gunicorn` for this you will declare `--chdir` because you want to run it from different folder:

```
web: gunicorn --chdir src myproject.wsgi --log-file -
```

On the other hand I'm not using `gunicorn` rather I declare it like this:

```
web: python myproject/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT --noreload
```

FYI - Switch to [gunicorn](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html#django) in production!

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second method works, but the gunicorn does not. I will just stick to the second approach from now on.

Comment: Glad I could help,  happy coding